# How can I decode custom Error with Combine?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, combine, urlsession

The API I'm making calls to can return JSON containing error message.

How can I tell `Combine` to try and decode this custom error if I'm expecting another `Decodable` object to be returned on successful request?

My code currently looks like this:

```
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

    internal func perform<T>(request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) where T: Decodable {
            cancellable = session.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
                .tryMap { output in
                    guard let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                        throw HTTPError.statusCode
                    }
                    return output.data
                }
                .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                .sink(receiveCompletion: { _completion in
                    guard case .failure(let error) = _completion else {
                        return
                    }
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }, receiveValue: { value in
                    completion(.success(value))
                })
}
```

With `URLSession` I would do something like this:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    // Check for any connection errors
    if let error = error {
        completion(.failure(error))
        return
    }
    // Read data
    guard let data = data, !data.isEmpty else {
        completion(.failure(SPTError.noDataReceivedError))
        return
    }
    // Check response's status code, if it's anything other than 200 (OK), try to decode SPTError from the data.
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
          httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
        let sptError = (try? JSONDecoder().decode(SPTError.self, from: data)) ?? SPTError.badRequest
        completion(.failure(sptError))
        return
    }
    // Decode requested objects
    do {
        let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        completion(.success(object))
    } catch {
        print(completion(.failure(error)))
    }
}.resume()
```

`SPTError` is just a struct that contains code and message, it conforms to `Codable`

Comment: And what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: It only attempts to decode `T` object, if response is different than `200` code it throws generic error and I'd like to decode the data as `SPTError`

Answer (score 2):

When you have conditional branching, you can use the `.flatMap` to determine which publisher to return based on whatever conditions you check.

`FlatMap` has to match the failure type of the upstream and the returned publisher, so need to `.mapError` first to a generic `Error`. And because different branch is a different publisher chain, type erase them all to `AnyPublisher`:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
   .mapError { $0 as Error }
   .flatMap() { output -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> in
      if output.data.isEmpty {
         return Fail(error: SPTError.noDataReceivedError).eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
        
      guard let httpResponse = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
         return Fail(error: HTTPError.statusCode).eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
        
      if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
         return Just(output.data)
            .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
      } else {
         return Just(output.data)
            .decode(type: SPTError.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .flatMap { Fail(error: $0) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
       }
   }
   .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```